# Doesn't displaying date period

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a problem with filtering date. I have SQL-query which are displayed all required parameters in certain date. I think that I also need create query which will return the same parameters, but with several required date.

Example: now in my query "2020-12-06", "2021-12-06". But I wanna get all data for period "2020-12-06" - "2021-12-06"
I tried create something, but best that I have - displaying for date which set, but not displaying period:

```
select ledgeraccounttypeid, dateeffective, sum(amount) from ledgertransaction
where ledgeraccounttypeid in (2,1,16) and dateeffective in('2020-12-06', '2021-12-06')
group by ledgeraccounttypeid, dateeffective
```

*Important: Period will set from program

**I will have: "YYYY.MM.DD" OR "YYYY.MM.DD - YYYY.MM.DD".

Comment: MySQL <> Postgresql. Please tag only one database.

Comment: What data type is `dateeffective`?

Comment: It is date type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want `between`?

```
where dateeffective between date '2020-12-06' and date '2021-12-06'
```

This assumes that `dateeffective` is of a date-like datatype, as it should be.

In many cases, half-open intervals better fit the needs:

```
where 
    dateeffective >= date '2020-12-06' 
    and dateeffective < date '2021-12-06' + interval '1' day
```

This syntax would work in both Postgrs and MySQL, also in the latter we would dispense the `date` keyword to introduce literal dates.

Comment: Yes, I wanna to get data from this period